# Can exponential time complexity converge to 0?

Tags: time-complexity

Is it possible to have an algorithm that has time complexity O(c^n) where c < 1? Every thing I see assumes that the operations grows rapidly. Here is an example of such a chart: http://bigocheatsheet.com/. It really bothers me that not a single introduction that I have seen mention this as a possibility but don't prove it as being impossible (if it is).

Comment: Well, you can make up silly contrived examples that behave that way. I can't think of a real problem that gets faster as the size of the input increases.

Comment: I guess at that point you would have to claim [thermal runaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_runaway) is computing...something.

Comment: The nil-algorithm is in that class (it always takes zero steps, and zero is still zero as n grows, no problem there), though you may then debate about what constitutes an algorithm in the first place.